# Find CakePHP - different query criteria

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple search form with 3 data and now not all data needs to be filled, some may stay empty ...

as they filled :

```
$this->Praca->find('all',array(
'conditions'=>array(
'kategoria'=>$wyniki['kategoria'][0],
'wojewodztwo'=>$wyniki['wojewodztwo'],
'poziom'=>$wyniki['poziom']
)));
```

Now, fe. when $wyniki['kategoria'] is empty I must :

```
$this->Praca->find('all',array(
'conditions'=>array(
'wojewodztwo'=>$wyniki['wojewodztwo'],
'poziom'=>$wyniki['poziom']
)));
```

To many possibilities, I need to find a SMART way, any idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fazel way you need to add conditions per each node. But case below you can add conditions as many as you want

```
$conditions = array();
$i=1;
foreach ($wyniki as $key=>$wyn){
    if(!empty($wyniki[$key])){
        $conditions[$i++] = array($key=>$wyn);  //or array($key=>end($wyn))
    }
}
$this->Praca->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$conditions = array();

if(!empty($wyniki['kategoria'][0])){
    $conditions = array('kategoria'=>$wyniki['kategoria'][0]);  
}
```

and so on...
........

```
$this->Praca->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```